# How can i get my deck to display ? It keeps saying null

Tags: java, arrays

Some help needed here. How can i get the deck to be display. Can't seem to make them display. Keeps saying `Card` is null. Using a `Main` file to call the `displayDeck` method.

```
public class deck {
public Card[] deck;

public void CreateDeck(){
    Card[] deck = new Card[52];
    String[] suit = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    int[] number = {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13};

    deck[0] = new Card("Spades",1);
    deck[1] = new Card("Spades",2);
    deck[2] = new Card("Spades",3);
    deck[3] = new Card("Spades",4);
    deck[4] = new Card("Spades",5);
    deck[5] = new Card("Spades",6);
    deck[6] = new Card("Spades",7);
    deck[7] = new Card("Spades",8);
    deck[8] = new Card("Spades",9);
    deck[9] = new Card("Spades",10);
    deck[10] = new Card("Spades",11);
    deck[11] = new Card("Spades",12);
    deck[12] = new Card("Spades",13);



    deck[13] = new Card("Clubs",1);
    deck[14] = new Card("Clubs",2);
    deck[15] = new Card("Clubs",3);
    deck[16] = new Card("Clubs",4);
    deck[17] = new Card("Clubs",5);
    deck[18] = new Card("Clubs",6);
    deck[19] = new Card("Clubs",7);
    deck[20] = new Card("Clubs",8);
    deck[21] = new Card("Clubs",9);
    deck[22] = new Card("Clubs",10);
    deck[23] = new Card("Clubs",11);
    deck[24] = new Card("Clubs",12);
    deck[25] = new Card("Clubs",13);


    deck[26] = new Card("Heart",1);
    deck[27] = new Card("Heart",2);
    deck[28] = new Card("Heart",3);
    deck[29] = new Card("Heart",4);
    deck[30] = new Card("Heart",5);
    deck[31] = new Card("Heart",6);
    deck[32] = new Card("Heart",7);
    deck[33] = new Card("Heart",8);
    deck[34] = new Card("Heart",9);
    deck[35] = new Card("Heart",10);
    deck[36] = new Card("Heart",11);
    deck[37] = new Card("Heart",12);
    deck[38] = new Card("Heart",13);

    deck[39] = new Card("Diamonds",1);
    deck[40] = new Card("Diamonds",2);
    deck[41] = new Card("Diamonds",3);
    deck[42] = new Card("Diamonds",4);
    deck[43] = new Card("Diamonds",5);
    deck[44] = new Card("Diamonds",6);
    deck[45] = new Card("Diamonds",7);
    deck[46] = new Card("Diamonds",8);
    deck[47] = new Card("Diamonds",9);
    deck[48] = new Card("Diamonds",10);
    deck[49] = new Card("Diamonds",11);
    deck[50] = new Card("Diamonds",12);
    deck[51] = new Card("Diamonds",13);

}
public void displayDeck(){
    for (int i =0;i<=50;i++){
        System.out.println("Card " + (i+1)+ " is: " + deck)// display deck;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: deck[i] in display deck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding your variable "deck" in your constructor instead of using your public property.

```
public void CreateDeck(){
    //Before
    //Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    //Correction
    deck = new Card[52];

    String[] suit = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    int[] number = {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13};

    deck[0] = new Card("Spades",1);
    deck[1] = new Card("Spades",2);
    deck[2] = new Card("Spades",3);
    deck[3] = new Card("Spades",4);

    ...
}
```